# Split string won't work when passing a single item unless it has a comma after it. Why?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a split string function like so:

```
ALTER Function [dbo].[fnParmSplitter] 
   (@Parm Varchar(100) )
Returns @tblSplit Table (Parm Int) 
AS
BEGIN
    -- Append comma
    SET @Parm = @Parm + ','
    -- Indexes to keep position
    Declare @pos1 int
    Declare @pos2 int

    -- Start from first character
    SET @pos1 = 1
    SET @pos2 = 1

    WHILE @pos1 < LEN(@Parm)
    BEGIN
        SET @pos1 = CHARINDEX(',', @Parm, @pos1)
        INSERT @tblSplit SELECT CAST(Substring(@Parm, @pos2, @pos1-@pos2) AS int)
        -- Go to next non-comma character
        SET @pos2 = @pos1 + 1
        -- Search from the next character
        SET @pos1 = @pos1 + 1
    END
    RETURN
END
```

It works if I send it a string of items like this: `1,2,3` but if I try to send it a single item (`3`) it doesn't work unless I put in a comma after 3 (`3,`). I cannot figure out why, though I'm sure it's staring me in the face.

Comment: There is no C# or program that I can manipulate the code of in this at all. It's just part of a stored procedure that is called from Crystal Reports from a program that I don't have access to the source code of.

Comment: I did notice that today. However, I don't fully understand it. I'm still new to SQL on the job as I come from an AS400 background. I'd have to give it some further reading but I need something ASAP for the user who needs this report. Now it seems my split function is working but I'm not able to get the data I need when I run the stored proc.

Comment: I prefer to understand something before I just start using it so I can debug it when needed.

Comment: You mean like how you understand the function you're using now and can debug it when needed? Posting the function on Stack Overflow and saying "why isn't this working" is not exactly what I would call debugging something you understand.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you need your insert to read:

```
INSERT @tblSplit SELECT CAST(Substring(@Parm, @pos2, @pos1-@pos2) AS int)
```

The last parameter is the length so cannot be negative.  This gives for:

```
select * from [dbo].[fnParmSplitter]('1')
select * from [dbo].[fnParmSplitter]('1,2')
select * from [dbo].[fnParmSplitter]('1,')
```

The response:

```
Parm
-----------
1

(1 row(s) affected)

Parm
-----------
1
2

(2 row(s) affected)

Parm
-----------
1

(1 row(s) affected)
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a typo in the `substring` statement:

```
substring(@parm, @pos2, -@pos2)
```

should read

```
substring(@param, @pos2, @pos1 - @pos2)
```

[Example SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/684c1/3)

However, what you have in the question wouldn't work for any input. So I suspect there is something else going on.

Comment: Not sure how that happened, I checked the function and the typo isn't there in the function so the real problem exists. I'll edit above to fix the typo in this post. Thanks.

Comment: @DrPepperholik can you edit the SQL Fiddle to exhibit the problem, and then post the new link back?

Comment: Strange, it was giving me an error about left or substring or something like that earlier but now it's not. I'm not getting any results from my stored procedure unless I take the comma out though.

Answer (score 0):

The line causing your problem is:

```
INSERT @tblSplit SELECT CAST(Substring(@Parm, @pos2, -@pos2) AS int)
```

Replace the above line with:

```
INSERT @tblSplit SELECT CAST(Substring(@Parm, @pos2, @pos1 - @pos2) AS int)
```

Comment: A downvote with no comment or explanation?  Nice etiquette...very constructive

Comment: I downvoted because your first solution doesn't work for a large number of valid inputs. Keeping it in the answer doesn't seem to be very useful.

Comment: Edited my answer to get rid of non-useful stuff :)

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT:** I misunderstood the original question.  I thought the OP wanted to know *why* the line about the comma was necessary to the function, rather than why some strings being passed in weren't working.  Planning to delete once I know the conversation in the comments is over.

---

As part of your function, when you pass in a string with no commas you are effectively trying to run:

```
SELECT SUBSTRING(@Parm, 1, 0-1)
```

That returns a negative value, and errors out.

Your `@pos1` and `@pos2` variables both start out with a positive value, but the first line of your `WHILE` loop is setting `@pos1` to zero (the `CHARINDEX()` function returned 0 because there was no comma in your search string).

```
DECLARE @Parm VARCHAR(100)

SET @Parm = 'value'
SELECT CHARINDEX(',', @Parm, 1) -- returns zero, indicating no comma found

SET @Parm = @Parm + ','
SELECT CHARINDEX(',', @Parm, 1) -- returns 6, the position of a comma in the string.
```

You then subtract `@pos2` (with a value of 1) from `@pos1` (with a value of 0), and ask the `CHARINDEX()` function to return -1 values from `@Parm` starting with the first character. This isn't possible, and you receive an error message.

Comment: he explicitly adds a comma to the end of the string in the first line.

Comment: Thank you @Laurence, I misread the question.  I will either revise or delete.

Comment: Who said anything about a he. :) I also set pos1 and pos2 to be 1. So 0-1 won't happen.

Comment: @DrPepperholik, after you set Pos1 the first time you then reset it with the CHARINDEX() function. I'd misread your original question to assume that you were trying to figure out why your function included `SET @Parm = @Parm + ','`, and was saying that (without that line) if @Parm did not contain a comma, that CHARINDEX() would then set pos1 to 0

Comment: Let me know if that makes sense so I can delete my answer :)